# how to pass parameters to build.xml from java class?

Tags: java, ant

I have a list of projects which needs to  be run automatically. 
I can give their path(for src folder)as an array.
How can I pass parameters to ant build.xml so that it can build and generate the jars so that i can stage them into my server.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,and paste you build.xml .

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify property values via the CLI with -Dname=value

See the docs: 
https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html